# Trying to decr ref count of Tcl_Obj allocated in another thread

Tags: tcl

I compiled the sourceforge tcl executable, it passes all the tests supplied, and it runs with the same segfault I see in my downloaded executable, 8.6.9.  I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 (for legacy reasons) on an AMD processor.  ( I have run on ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, it has the same failure. )

So, next I recompiled with "--enable-symbols=mem" turned on to see if a memory leak is causing the segfault, and now it fails immediately with:

```
Trying to decr ref count of Tcl_Obj allocated in another thread
./runMeg.sh: line 3: 29972 Aborted (core dumped) ../source/main_megatron.
```

I'm not seeing any answer on what to do with this response, can someone advise on what this means I need to fix?

All my threads are of the form:

```
set graphDisplayThread [ thread::create {
  after [expr {int(1000) }]
  .....
  puts "...Initialized graphDisplayUpdate_02 ID $c update."
  thread::wait
  }]
```

and:

```
thread::send  $::graphDisplayThread { 
   incr b
   graphDisplayUpdate .c 
   }
```

All shared variables are referenced AFTER mutex is captured, and through TSV variables.   There are 5 threads in the application, which has no C-code in it at all. Around 2000 lines of code, in total.

The app runs thousands of cycles and then segfaults at random points with a prior ActiveState 8.6.9 pre-compiled version. So, now I'm trying to isolate the failure point with compiled SourceForge 8.6.9 memory checks as a first step, but the issue above is the first one I encounter - and it occurs immediately after starting.

Update (5/16/19 8:28 EST): New Detail to answer comments below.... This application has no C-code in it, and the Tcl_Obj error ONLY appears in the sourceForge-based, 8.6.9 compiles (2) I did myself, not the ActiveState 8.6.9 pre-built download.   And the error in the sourceForge code occurs in both the twin "MEM_DEBUG" and NO-"MEM_DEBUG" builds I made in tandem and tested.  Both passed all install tests.

To summarize:

```
sourceForge 8.6.9 compile w/MEM_DEBUG option:   Tcl_Obj Abort error 
sourceForge 8.6.9 compile w/o MEM_DEBUG option: Tcl_Obj Abort error
ActiveState 8.6.9 build:                    does not Abort, random seg fault
```

Why should I trust the sourceForge build I made myself, more than the ActiveState pre-built executable which does not exhibit the problem?  And if we do trust the sourceForge compiled version, how do I isolate where the TclObject error is created by the offending TCL code?

Update 5/16/19@13:34EST: The same segfault appears with ActiveState 8.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.  Haven't checked my builds of SourceForge yet to see how they behave.

Comment: You will have to show C code, the debug statement "[...] Tcl_Obj allocated in another thread" shows that your C code tries to dispose (decrement) a Tcl_Obj in one thread (interp) that was created by another (thread) interp.

Comment: "All shared variables are referenced AFTER mutex is captured, and through TSV variables." ... this sounds like duplicated effort, TSV internally set mutex protection so they should be not needed around tsv calls.

Comment: "memory leak causing the segfault" ... there is no memory leak, there is an access violation in terms of Tcl's thread and storage model. To that end, `--enable-symbols=mem` is not insightful, because your problem is not about balancing increments and decrements over the lifecycle of a Tcl_Obj, but about not accessing a Tcl_Obj between threads.

Comment: 1st comment reply:  mrcalvin, I have no Ccode in this application.  How do I "show C code" and connect that to the applicable TCL code causing the problem?  Any guide you can point to for helping me get under the covers on this is appreciated.

Comment: 2nd comment reply:  The app has a number of TSV lists which all must be prepared in lock-step, so the mutex only allows other threads to read the three arrays when all 3 have been completely populated.

Does that now sound appropriate to use a mutex to synchronize data reads from the multiple arrays ?

Comment: 3rd comment reply:  OK, I see I need to find this decrement/increment issue.   My concern is this error only appears in the build I built, but not in the ActiveState 8.6.9 build I downloaded and ran w/o compile.    Could the build I made have a compilation error in it, even if it passed all the install tests?

Comment: I updated the comments in the question, at the bottom, so let me know and i'll delete the 3 replies I just made, if they are no longer interesting.

Comment: can you post a minimal, self-contained script that shows the exact error (Tcl_Obj not allocated ...) so that one can try to reproduce?

Comment: As I chopped out sections of code to minimize the test case, I found one issue:  I had created the mutex's more than one time.  So I fixed that.  By using a delete-n-relaunch process, I hope to isolate other issues tomorrow, for the app still shows the same error, but later in the launch cycle.

Answer (score 0):

By methodically hacking out code blocks and watching to see if the Tcl_Obj error dissappeared or not, I found 2 errors:

- I had re-declared my mutex and cond variables more than once.  Now it is declared once and referenced in all other places.
- A code remnant removing a TSV was found in a place I no longer wanted it.

This also fixed the segfault.

Thanks for all the help and hints, mrcalvin.

Comment: Glad you got your application stable, after all. However, any chance you can share the minimal, verifiable script so that we can investigate the issue? From the script level, via [`thread`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/thread) extension, one should never be able to end up in an `[...] Tcl_Obj allocated in another thread` error.

Comment: Can you message me to discuss this?  I tried ripping some code out, it didn't replicate the error at that point.  The error only started appearing as the code size got larger.

Comment: The error occurs deeper into my simulation, so if I chop out large sections of codes, it fails execution before the Tcl_Obj fail.  I could send you the whole tar ball if you want.  Message me if interested.

Comment: how should I send you a private message exactly? any chance you could hang out with us at [IRC](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Chatroom)?

Comment: Please message me at johndlofgren@gmail.com.